# Colocation of other backend services with Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'd like to use Next JS hosted on Vercel but with an external backend services eg PlanetScale / Supabase, etc.

Assume I have a React Server Component that calls one of these backend services. My understanding is that first Vercel's function is called to render the component, and that function will call the external backend service.

If that's correct, then is it important to colocate Vercel and the backend service to reduce latency? How does one do this?

Answer (score 0):

"[Understanding React Server Components](https://vercel.com/blog/understanding-react-server-components)" confirms that, when using Next.js hosted on Vercel, the typical flow for a React Server Component would involve calling a Vercel serverless function to render the component.
And in your case, that function would *then* make an API call to the external backend service.

That two-step approach can introduce additional latency due to the round-trip time required for the Vercel function to communicate with the external service.

Colocation of Vercel and the backend service in the same geographical region should mitigate this latency to some extent. You might consider:

- choosing a hosting region for your Vercel application that is geographically close to where your external backend service is hosted. That would minimize the latency for API calls between the Vercel serverless functions and the backend service. For example, if your PlanetScale or Supabase service is hosted in a U.S. East data center, you should consider deploying your Vercel application to a U.S. East region as well.
  See also "[How do I choose which region to deploy my Serverless Functions in?](https://vercel.com/guides/choosing-deployment-regions)"
- enabling CDN Caching: [Vercel automatically deploys your Next.js application to a Content Delivery Network (CDN) close to your users](https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/caching). For read-heavy operations, you might want to consider caching the results at the CDN layer. That would reduce the need for the Vercel function to make frequent calls to the external backend.
- use Server-Side Caching to store frequently accessed data. That way, you can reduce the number of times the Vercel function needs to call the external backend service.
- optimize Queries and API Calls: make sure you are only fetching the necessary data, and consider using batch requests where possible.

The [PlanetScale / Deploy to Vercel](https://planetscale.com/docs/tutorials/deploy-to-vercel) primarily discusses the steps for integrating the two services at a functional level, using environment variables or Vercel's marketplace integrations.
It does not specifically address the issue of colocation or geographical proximity between Vercel and the PlanetScale database.
Same for the [Vercel PlanetScale integration page](https://vercel.com/integrations/planetscale). Or for the [Admin Dashboard Template](https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-planetscale-nextauth-tailwindcss-template), which uses PlanetScale.